# Javascript function definition performance

Tags: javascript, optimization, function-definition

What is the nature of performance considerations regarding the definition (not execution) of functions? What can lead to performance degradation, and what cases tend to be handled efficiently in modern js environments?

Some comparisons to consider are:

*Defining functions in-loop vs out-of-loop (functions never use external references):*

```js
let cases = {
  defineFnInLoop: testArr => {
    for (let elem of testArr) {
      let fn = elem => elem;
      fn(elem);
    }
  },
  defineFnBeforeLoop: testArr => {
    let fn = elem => elem;
    for (let elem of testArr) fn(elem);
  }
};

// You can ignore (or scrutinize, if you prefer!) this test code:
(async (batches=50, runs=20*1000, sleepMs=50, constElems=100, elemsPerBatch=100) => {
  let timing = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(cases).map(([ k, fn ]) => [ k, 0 ]));
  let arr = [ ...new Array(constElems) ].map(v => null);
  for (let i = 0; i < batches; i++) {
    arr.push(...[ ...new Array(elemsPerBatch) ].map(v => null));
    // Interleaved testing of cases helps mitigate effect of CPU fluctuations
    for (let k in cases) {
      let fn = cases[k];
      // Timing sensitive segment; I've done my best to reduce the overhead:
      let ms = +new Date(); for (let j = 0; j < runs; j++) fn(arr); timing[k] += new Date() - ms;
    }
    console.log(`Finished batch ${i + 1} / ${batches} (arr size: ${arr.length})`);
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, sleepMs));
  }
  let [ best, ...others ] = Object.entries(timing).sort((v1, v2) => v1[1] - v2[1]);
  console.log(`Winner: ${best[0]} (${best[1]}ms)`);
  for (let [ name, ms ] of others)
    console.log(`Loser:  ${name} (${ms}ms; ${(100 * ms / best[1] - 100).toFixed()}% slower)`); 
})();
```

*Defining functions in-loop vs out-of-loop, potentially with external references:*

```js
let cases = {
  useExternalRefInLoop: testArr => {
    let ref = null;
    for (let elem of testArr) {
      let fn = elem => (elem, ref);
      fn(elem);
    }
  },
  noExternalRefInLoop: testArr => {
    let ref = null;
    for (let elem of testArr) {
      let fn = elem => (elem, elem);
      fn(elem);
    }
  },
  useExternalRefOutLoop: testArr => {
    let ref = null;
    let fn = elem => (elem, ref);
    for (let elem of testArr) fn(elem);
  },
  noExternalRefOutLoop: testArr => {
    let ref = null;
    let fn = elem => (elem, elem);
    for (let elem of testArr) fn(elem);
  }
};

// You can ignore (or scrutinize, if you prefer!) this test code:
(async (batches=50, runs=20*1000, sleepMs=50, constElems=100, elemsPerBatch=100) => {
  let timing = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(cases).map(([ k, fn ]) => [ k, 0 ]));
  let arr = [ ...new Array(constElems) ].map(v => null);
  for (let i = 0; i < batches; i++) {
    arr.push(...[ ...new Array(elemsPerBatch) ].map(v => null));
    // Interleaved testing of cases helps mitigate effect of CPU fluctuations
    for (let k in cases) {
      let fn = cases[k];
      // Timing sensitive segment; I've done my best to reduce the overhead:
      let ms = +new Date(); for (let j = 0; j < runs; j++) fn(arr); timing[k] += new Date() - ms;
    }
    console.log(`Finished batch ${i + 1} / ${batches} (arr size: ${arr.length})`);
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, sleepMs));
  }
  let [ best, ...others ] = Object.entries(timing).sort((v1, v2) => v1[1] - v2[1]);
  console.log(`Winner: ${best[0]} (${best[1]}ms)`);
  for (let [ name, ms ] of others)
    console.log(`Loser:  ${name} (${ms}ms; ${(100 * ms / best[1] - 100).toFixed()}% slower)`); 
})();
```

I've run this same code using jsbench.me, with the same results:

- [Comparison 1](https://jsbench.me/2jkgmj0oil/1)
- [Comparison 2](https://jsbench.me/owkgmj5zyd/1)

I get surprising results for both comparisons. Defining the function once per iteration is faster for me than defining the function a single time, before the loop. Also, functions which refer to external references (non-parameter references) seem *faster* than functions which refer only to their parameters!! I found this especially surprising when the function used an external reference, and was defined repeatedly within the loop - I thought that the external reference would reduce the interpreter's ability to mitigate the effect of repeated function definition. *I was confident `useExternalRefInLoop` would be slowest, but it was the second fastest, and within a tiny percent of being the overall winner!*

ISSUES: These tests define small functions, which impede the isolation of the performance impact of function definition alone. I am not 100% certain that my test code or test cases are 100% kosher. Finally, my environment (SO's snippet system, within up-to-date Edge browser) may not speak for all environments, and optimizations in general may vary environment-to-environment.

QUESTIONS:

- It looks like the interpreter has a clever way of optimizing repeated definition of the same function, and even may *prefer* functions which use external references! **Should we always prefer to define our functions in-loop, and should we prefer external references (in terms of performance, only), or are there factors which circumstantially prevent these optimizations and cause these tactics to *reduce* performance?**?
- What are other pertinent performance considerations regarding function definition? (Too broad I'm sure, but I would appreciate any insight anyone would like to offer!)

Note: premature optimization is a thing to be discouraged, but not all optimization is premature!

Comment: Things to take into consideration: **1-** parsing of the functions of both type of declaration is only done once, parsing here is of crucial importance since you don't care about actually calling the function. **2-** javascript engines nowadays are way optimized, so you don't know how the compiler/interpreter actually handles the second case, it may detect that the function is the same and move it outside. **3-** this type of benchmarks doesn't always yield accurate results, the results should not be taken as proof for anything

Comment: To the closer/downvoter - I've edited to ask a very focused question, adding the very broad question merely as a side-point.

Comment: Note that the fact you are asking multiple questions can be thought of as too broad (The "Needs focus" close reason has the subscript "This question currently includes multiple questions in one.").

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir regarding **1** - there must be some difference, though, if the results differ by a non-trivial margin *unless* this testing setup is completely invalid **2** - I find it unlikely that this setup is *completely* invalid, since results seem to be repeatable, and the testing code doesn't introduce any obvious favouritism.

Comment: Consider using a benchmarking site like https://www.measurethat.net/, https://jsbench.me/, etc., or a benchmarking library like https://benchmarkjs.com/. Homemade benchmarks are almost always poorly made.

Comment: @HereticMonkey you're right. I'll venture to keep the 2nd question for now, since the possibility of getting good insight seems worth it! I'll include a link to one of those sites.

Comment: @Gershom your test cases are wrong anyway, because you said you want to compare the difference in performance between defining the function inside the loop or outside it, but you are calling the function which takes most of the time. You should be comparing `let fn = elem => elem;` vs `for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) let fn = elem => elem;` , and we know which one will win this contest

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir well that's why I needed the loop: to compare defining inside/outside the function, with all else (including the presence of a loop) remaining constant. Of the tests you propose, one is a superset of the other!

Comment: I would assume that the biggest issue with this benchmark is that the functions don't do anything. They will get inlined, and then their call and entire body will get optimised away.

Comment: https://jsbench.me/igkgmk39zm/1 clearly outside the loop is much faster. Inside is ~60% slower

Comment: That's interesting, I get different results inline with what I see here! I'll give these tests a shot in other browsers and in node.